# jQuery Mobile disable enhancement on certain tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I don't want the styles for the `<a>` tag. I've found threads like this [How to "turn off" jQuery Mobile's styling of <select> drop downs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348757/how-to-turn-off-jquery-mobiles-styling-of-select-drop-downs) but I don't want to be adding `data-enhance=false` to every anchor I have. I was also hoping `linkBindingEnabled` would work (from http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html), as in it wouldn't add custom classes to the `<a>` tag.

I could delete the definitions in the CSS file, but I'd prefer a programmatic way to do it. For example, I comment out `.ui-body-c .ui-link` (the default link), but then my links in the footer are still enhanced. And I'm sure there are other little cases, and I don't want to make it messy (although sometimes that's the only option)

Basically, is there a way to disable enhancement for a "selector" of elements? Instead of manually adding `data-enhance=false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few ways of disabling markup enhancement in **`jQuery Mobile`** but in your case there's only one single line solution:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
   $('a').removeClass('ui-link');
});
```

**`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/L4KUT/

Other solutions can be found in my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, to be transparent it is my personal blog. Or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**. Search for the chapter called:  **Methods of markup enhancement prevention**.

There you will find a answer how to disable it on a selector level, unfortunately it only works on native form elements and a tag is not a native form element:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
     $.mobile.page.prototype.options.keepNative = "select, input";
});
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked. However, I'm not using pages, (I just have `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {`, so I'm a little confused about how that works (because I don't specify a page to load, although I think JQM will auto create a page). Do you know any links, our could explain, the order in which events are called? Like just a complete timeline when I load a fresh page

Comment: Yes I do, I have another answer/article about this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600

Answer (score 5):

To disable enhancement of a select component you can add `data-role='none'`, tested on jQuery Mobile 1.4.2.

see http://jsfiddle.net/zLZzA/1/

Comment: What if you have 100+ components on a page? Are you going to add that to each and every one?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Also works with jQuery Mobile 1.3.2