# Disable active button in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation bar and I've been able to fix its behaviour as I like with this jQuery code:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
        $.mobile.activeBtnClass = 'unused';
    });
```

But this way I disable ALL the buttons in my webapp...

I'd like to aim it to a specific set of buttons.

How can I achieve that?

I'd do:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
        $(".myclass").activeBtnClass = 'unused';
    });
```

or

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
        $(".myclass").mobile.activeBtnClass = 'unused';
    });
```

But this won't work...

What is wrong?

Comment: Might this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914756/jquery-mobile-disable-enhancement-on-certain-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion was interesting, roXon, but since I wanted to let the user understand where he was while using my webapp.

Fortunately jQuery guys thought about this kind of issue and I have been able to solve the problem very easily adding class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" so my button.

Thanks anyway!