Dropdown option default display issue in jquery mobile
I do not want the dropdown default selected option to display separately but why is this happening.
Is there an option to skip the jquery setting for a particular dropdown? Like using some function like preventDefault ?
Please refer the below url.
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/ufLr0wo2/
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-rc1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.min.js"></script>  
    
</head>

    <body>      
<div class="">  
    
<form>
        <select>
            <option value="0">item 0</option>
            <option>item 1</option>
            <option>item 2</option>
        </select>
</form>

</div>
    </body>
    </html>


Hi , what do you mean you dont want the default option to display separately?

@AmenawonEsezobor: when the page opens, the first option of dropdown is coming as a separate display text adjacent to it. Why so?

@sqlchild do you want to hide name all time or just for the first time when page loads?

@Death-is-the-real-truth all time

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23054635/1771795

use <select data-role='none'> to fix the issue
