# jQuery select- How to change the css style select?

Tags: jquery, html, css, select

I use `<select>` in order to create a selection filter. My problem that I the css of the jQuery takes over the regular style of the css of `<select>`. How can I make the select display as the regular `<select>` in HTML?

```
<div id="mutualFriends">

    <select class="sortBy" name="sortBy" data-url="/threebaysover/profile/sortFollowers">
        <option value="">Sort By</option>
        <option value="new" selected="selected">Newest</option>
        <option value="old">Oldest</option>
        <option value="firstName_asc">First Name a-z</option>
        <option value="firstName_desc">First Name z-a</option>
        <option value="lastName_asc">Last Name a-z</option>
        <option value="lastName_desc">Last Name z-a</option>
        <option value="message">Recent message</option>
        <option value="company_asc">Company Name a-z</option>
        <option value="company_desc">Company Name z-a</option>
    </select>

    <div id="mutual">
```

Comment: Check out http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ It will style a select box, and other useful options.

And jQuery.SimpleSelect (http://pioul.fr/jquery-simpleselect) too.

Comment: What CSS of jQuery? Are you using jQuery UI? Do you have a jsFiddle or Codepen that shows the problem?

Comment: @ckuijjer - I'm using jQuery Mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `data-role="none"` to the `<select>` element when you don't want jQuery UI to restyle the element. See [How to "turn off" jQuery Mobile's styling of <select> drop downs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348757/how-to-turn-off-jquery-mobiles-styling-of-select-drop-downs)

Comment: Do u know how can I change the icon of the arrows to a specific icon I need?

Comment: Browsers don't allow for much styling of `<select>` boxes. The only option would be to position an image on top of the `<select>` box. If you want to style the `<select>` box I would suggest you to look at  a JavaScript library that replaces the `<select>` element with some `<div>` structure, like ivaynberg.github.io/select2 as @Marta Fernandez noted.